# Linux capture window of a large stream of data

Tags: linux, stream, window

Let's say I have a ton of data flowing through stdout over a long period of time, maybe an hour, and I want to capture a 30 second window of that data based on a trigger that occurs in the middle of that window.  For instance, maybe something like

```
$ program-that-outputs-lots-of-data | program-that-captures-a-window-of-data
```

At some point, a line that contains "A-unique-string" will be output by the program, and at that point I want to save the 15 seconds worth of data before and after that string, discarding everything before that.  Immediately afterward, I want to start monitoring again for the same string and capture another window when it comes in and save it to a new file.  Any idea how I can do something like this with Linux tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that you are trying to use **time** as a unit for buffering makes your problem very rare.  Under the Unix command line, everything tends to be designed around the **text line** concept.

For example, if instead of 15 *seconds* of data you would like to capture 15 lines of text (before and after the special token), you could simply do:

```
$ program-that-outputs-lots-of-data | grep -C 15 A-unique-string
```

In your case, even if you are developing your own tailored filtering tool, deciding how much input to save and to discard is a pretty complex problem.  I'd say that multimedia streaming is the area where there might be some ready to use tools.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I was considering a line count option rather than time based, and the grep -C is probably the simplest way to do that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think anything exists that approaches these goals.  Aside from the fact that your requirements are fairly specific, you also ask that the window be time-based, whereas most Unix-style text filters are line-oriented (e.g. `grep -C 100` to get the hundred lines surrounding a match).

It should be fairly straightforward to do this in Python or Perl or Ruby or a similar scripting language.

Comment: As below, thanks for the info. I was considering a line count option rather than time based, and the grep -C is probably the simplest way to do that. Thanks!